# Merging XML with duplicate entries with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have two XML configuration files, one global XML file that's located on the web and one that exists locally. Each may contain unique elements. The local config file may contain additional attributes for items that exist in the global config. I would like to merge the two lists together such that the local configuration takes precidence over the global. For example...

Local Configuration File:

```
  <Applications>
    <Application name="Mozilla Firefox 24.2.0" default="true"/>
    <Application name="Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client"/>
  </Applications>
```

Global Configuration File:

```
  <Applications>
    <Application name="Mozilla Firefox 24.2.0"/>
    <Application name="Google Chrome 31.0"/>
  </Applications>
```

Merged Configuration File:

```
  <Applications>
    <Application name="Mozilla Firefox 24.2.0" default="true"/>
    <Application name="Google Chrome 31.0"/>
    <Application name="Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client"/>
  </Applications>
```

Effective I think I want to do a union and then merge any elements that are duplicated. I dont know if this helps but the global config is basically static so the default attribute is only present in the local config. I don't actually need to output the XML file I just need to be able to end up with the merged content somehow. I can get them both in to my program and them compare manually but it seems like there must be a more effecient way. I find lots of examples that are reasonably close to what I want to do but nothing that quite fits exactly.

Here's an example of the code I have now that actually does work the way I want it to but it seems like it must be rather ineffecient.

```
    public ObservableCollection<CheckableItem<string>> getAvailableApplications()
    {
        IEnumerable<String> apps = from e in config.Descendants("Application") orderby e.Attribute("name").Value select e.Attribute("name").Value;
        IEnumerable<String> localApps = from e in defaults.Descendants("Application") orderby e.Attribute("name").Value select e.Attribute("name").Value;
        apps = apps.Union(localApps);
        ObservableCollection<CheckableItem<string>> collection = new ObservableCollection<CheckableItem<string>>();

        foreach (string app in apps)
        {
            bool isDef = false;
            IEnumerable<String> defs = from x in defaults.Descendants("Application") where x.Attribute("name").Value.Equals(app) select x.Attribute("default").Value;
            try
            {
                isDef = System.Convert.ToBoolean(defs.SingleOrDefault());
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Default for {0} not specified", app);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid default value specified for app {0}", app);
            }
            CheckableItem<string> item = new CheckableItem<string>(app);
            if (isDef)
                item.IsChecked = true;
            collection.Add(item);
        }
        return collection;
    }
```

Comment: You probably forgot to paste your code

Comment: I pasted the code that I have currently. If I can't find a better way I can just use that for what I want to do. It's not really big deal but I'd rather do it the right way.